# curl command for REST API which takes json input

Tags: json, rest, api, curl

I want to call REST API by passing json input.
I have following details-

username
apitoken
apiurl
Jsonfile

I have already tried 
curl -d @Metadata.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" <> --user xyz:apitoken --insecure

but i m getting null values for all the parameters in the json file.
What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Solution would be to create a sample postman with above details then follow below steps -

- Click on the code icon.
- Choose cURL from the drop-down.
  ***There’s your cURL command***

Sample curl command -

```
 curl -X POST \
 https://something.com/endpoint \
 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
 -H 'Postman-Token: 1f0fcc007739' \
 -H 'apikey: CSZftBtR0WaN' \
 -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
 -d '{
     "Id": "5de675",
      "xxxxx": "500081"
 }'
```